# Unity: Registering the same type for two interfaces

Tags: c#, unity-container

I'm seeing a weird behaviour in the Unity container, when working with two interfaces, that both register to the same decorator. A code example will be clearer.

I have the following class hierarchy:

```
   public interface IBaseInterface
    {

    }

    public interface IInterface1: IBaseInterface
    {

    }
    public interface IInterface2: IBaseInterface
    {

    }
    public class Interface1Impl : IInterface1
    {
    }
    public class Interface2Impl : IInterface2
    {
    }

    public class BaseInterfaceDecorator: IInterface1,IInterface2
    {
        private readonly IBaseInterface baseInterface;

        public BaseInterfaceDecorator(IBaseInterface baseInterface)
        {
            this.baseInterface = baseInterface;
        }
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        private readonly IInterface1 interface1;

        public MyClass(IInterface1 interface1)
        {
            this.interface1 = interface1;
        }            
    }
```

And this is the registration code:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();           
        container.RegisterType<IInterface1, BaseInterfaceDecorator>(
            new InjectionConstructor(
                new ResolvedParameter<Interface1Impl>()));

        container.RegisterType<IInterface2, BaseInterfaceDecorator>(
           new InjectionConstructor(
               new ResolvedParameter<Interface2Impl>()));


        var dependency = container.Resolve<MyClass>();
```

When resolving MyClass I'm getting a BaseInterfaceDecorator with Interface2Impl instead of Interface1Impl. Seems strange to me. Can you explain?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like the last injection instruction for a given "to" type wins.  If you grab a copy of [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) and take a look at the `UnityContainer.RegisterType(Type, Type, string, LifetimeManager, InjectionMember[])` implementation, you'll see why.

IMO, this behaviour is a bug.  At the very least, `InjectedMembers.ConfigureInjectionFor(Type, string, InjectionMember[])` should throw an exception instead of silently replacing the previous injection configuration.  However, it really ought to support what you are attempting.

Comment: In case this isn't clear to readers; Internally Unity caches the Build Key of the 'to' type (e.g. 'TTo' in generic signatures.) The next time you resolve any 'TFrom' type the Build Key for 'TTo' is used to perform build up. This build key is also associated with a lifetime manager and thus Unity appears to use the first-used lifetime manager (in Build Up) for all subsquent resolves for TTo (regardless of the identity of TFrom.)

This is a bug with Unity's Build Keys. The workaround is to use named registrations, which defeats the point in estabilishing covariant type identities.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it helps. It's most likely too late for you by now. But, this is achievable if you use named registration, i.e. you register each type to be resolved with a different name.

For example:

```
Container.RegisterType<IInterface1, BaseInterfaceDecorator>("interface1");
Container.RegisterType<IInterface2, BaseInterfaceDecorator>("interface2");
```

Comment: This is a valid workaround, but it defeats the purpose in using covariant types in registration. Unity makes the assumption that all resolves for 'TTo' refer to the same configuration/instructions for creating a TTo instance. Thus, you will see problems with Injection Parameters and Lifetime Management where TFrom's identity should be resulting in different behavior (different injection parms, different lifetime manager, etc.)